# Apache Camel JPA: update a column based on a column in another table

Tags: apache-camel

I have two entities Entity1 and Entity2. This what I need to do as part of my route.

I need to read Entity1 and get a column value, take that column value and update that to a column in Entity2.

How can I do this using Camel Jpa?

Comment: Should be pretty straight forward. You can retrieve and store entities with Camel JPA. Many Camel constructs or a plain java bean can map between them. What have you tried?

Comment: @Petter I used JPA component in my route and just tried to update a column, that worked fine with using Consumed method. For now I used namedquery and passed some constant query. So this is what I am observing now, I talked with one of our architects here and he suggested to use JDBC component rather than JPA. Can you suggest me what to use. Also if possible can you type in some high level pseudo code here....